# python function for bayesiasn information criterion (BIC)

Tags: python, model, statistics, bayesian

I am learning about the bayesian information criterion (BIC) to choose the model which represents better a set of data points, and I would like to compute a python function that evaluates the BIC value.

I know the theory and the main equation:`BIC=ln(n)k -2ln(L)` (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) )
but I don't understand, practically, what I have to do.

I have a set of data points and a model, but which are the logic passages to implement `L` in my function?

- `n` is the number of data points
- `k` is the number of free parameters in my model
- `L` is the maximized value of the likelihood function of the model which I don't know how to compute

As an alternative, there is a package that has already implemented some BIC function?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @dang I am looking at an easier equation [here](https://pypi.org/project/RegscorePy/):

`BIC = n*log(residual sum of squares/n) + k*log(n)`

which sounds more familiar, my only question is about the `k` value, I am not sure that it refers to the number of total parameters or the number of free parameters in my model.

But I have a doubt: according to the Wikipedia page, this second equation is an approximation in the case of "the model errors or disturbances are independent and identically distributed according to a normal distribution".
Is that approximation reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that the better option is to write your own function, based on your data.
To answer one of my questions above, `k` is the number of free parameters in the model, not the total number of parameters (i.e., parameters that rea not free, are frozen).

My own function is simply:

```
def BIC_calc(free_param, stat, dof):
    n = dof + free_param
    k = free_param
    return stat + np.log(n)*k
```

Comment: What is stat, n and dof?

Comment: in my case BIC=ln(n)k -2ln(L), L is the likelihood of model parameter given the data , do you have any idea , how should i calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

googling `bayesian information criterion python` yields the [RegscorePy library](https://pypi.org/project/RegscorePy/) on pypi. Its BIC function seems helpful.

Comment: please put his on "add a comment", because it is not an answer. My data are discrete.

Comment: I cannot comment, less than 50 reputation. I will delete now that I have my info :)